# How can I remove a constant alias in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

How can I remove a constant alias in Powershell? I have tried some solutions, but I still get the same error.

I tried to remove the "sl" alias, but I received an error message saying "Remove-Alias: Alias was not removed because alias sl is constant or read-only."

```
Remove-Alias -Force -Name sl
```

I tried get "Option" of the alias.

```
> (Get-Alias sl).Options
# ReadOnly, Constant, AllScope
```

I tried to change the alias options, but I received the following error.

```
> Set-ItemProperty -Path "Alias:sl" -Name "Options" -Value (\[System.Management.Automation.ScopedItemOptions\]::None)

# Set-ItemProperty: Cannot use interface. The IPropertyCmdletProvider interface is not supported by this provider.
```

Powershell Version：7.4.0 preview.3

Comment: Why do you want to? Error seems straight forward enough, it's a system alias that comes as part of powershell, you're essentially trying to delete a powershell command. That can't be changed otherwise any other powershell script (including those used by the system) that used that alias would break / function incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry i can't reproduce your problem on PowerShell 7.2.11

```
PS C:\Users\xxx> Remove-Alias -Name sl
Remove-Alias: Alias was not removed because alias sl is constant or read-only.
PS C:\Users\xxx> Remove-Alias -Name sl -Force
PS C:\Users\xxx> sl
sl: The term 'sl' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for yours reply. This is not system alias, it is from "Set-Alias -Name sl -Value 'C:\Program Files\Sapling\sl.exe' -Force -Option Constant,ReadOnly,AllScope" Command. Sapling is is a source control system and I want to remove it.

Comment: @user21822818 `sl` is a short-hand alias for Set-Location (at least in PS 7.3.8) and is definitely a system alias. I am not a PS expert, but my wild guess is that the `Set-Alias` command you mention has overwritten the system alias somehow. If that's the case, I am not sure why `Set-Alias` was allowed and `Remove-Alias` with the `-Force` flag is not.

Answer (score 0):

You can forcefully remove `sl` with:

```
Remove-Item -Force Alias:sl
```